# Cytoscape.js in Angular 13 can't import cytoscape extensions

Tags: angular, graph, cytoscape.js

I have an application in Angular 13. I have imported cytoscape.js following these steps:

1. Install cytoscape using `npm install --save-exact cytoscape`
2. Install cytoscape types using `npm install --save-dev --save-exact @types/cytoscape`

Now Cytoscape.js works , I created a graph. But I can't import any extension:

I need to import an extension from the library, but cannot import any of them. I have this error:

```
The plugin library did not have a type definition that make "import * as cytoscape 
from 'cytoscape';" not possible
```